# Is it "stern talking too", or "stern talking to"?

Tags: colloquialisms

In the following sentence:

> I'll have to give myself a stern talking to.

is it "stern talking to", or "stern talking too"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merriam-Webster and the New Oxford American Dictionary say it's a *stern talking-to*, with a hyphen.

Answer (score 4):

If you're fine with talking to someone frankly, you tend to phrase it in terms of, well, just talking to them.

> I will have to talk to Bob.
>   I will have to give the same talk to Sue.
>   I will have to give that talk to Greg, too.
>   I will also be talking to Fred.

Most people who use *a talking to* as a noun do so to describe some chore or other unpleaseant responsibility.

> Gracie wet the bed. I will have to give her a talking to.

Knowledgeable English scholars are able to tell the difference.

> I tried to talk to Molly, but she was too busy listening to Diane. Now I need to give Diane a talking to too.

*Talking to* is an old-fashioned verb form (or nounification, if that's a word*) that reflects the idea that superiors talking to a junior were talking *to* them, not *with* them.

Hence, if you would like to have a better relationship with your inner self, you're probably better off *conversing* or *discussing* or, heaven forbid, *understanding*. If you don't have such a good relationship with your inner self you could *encourage* or *cajole* or *persuade*. To give yourself a *stern talking to* is a sign that you regard your subconscious mind as a child. You're probably better off giving yourself some encouragement and a stern talking to too.

*Oh, wow, it is.

Comment: ***Nominalization*** is the word you want, but *nounification* is perfectly compositional, as well as cromulent. All of these are *Event Nominalizations* of transitive verbs, usually denoting unpleasant events, like _give X a whipping/licking/beating/lashing/talking to_, which are equivalent to _whip/lick/beat/lash/talk to X_, respectively. The _to_ is necessary because _talk_ is intransitive and requires a transitivizing preposition.

Answer (score 3):

In the expression, the people are talking TO themselves, so it's *a talking to.*